# Efficient pagination where the database is SQL Server and front-end is angular

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination, primeng-datatable

In my web application page loads very slowly because the SQL that drives the page at the backend executes very slowly. rownumber() was used but that did not improve the situation.I understand that keyset pagination is most efficient. I have read this [keyset pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)
  Take the case of following query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
AND id < ?last_seen_id
ORDER BY id DESC
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Now how I know last_seen_id in case of first page? My front-end is Angular & PrimeNG. The stored procedure behind the page is also slow.DISTINCT clause have been used. There are 12  joins.

Comment: Would creating a table with all `id`s not yet inserted be possible?

Comment: @George Menoutis, I have looked at the corresponding table, id is not auto-generated, it is created by another tool over which I do not have any control.So the answer is negative.

Comment: I did not propose you to change the `id`. But if you could create a temporary table that holds the `id`s, you could get your batch each time. I can provide a detailed answer if you think it's feasible.

Comment: @George Menoutis, I can create a view which will have only the id column. I can even create another table which will hold only the ids. Not clear why you want the table to be temporary.But yes, can create temporary table as well.